# 'v-if' does not work when added to the 'return' function. Why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, return

`v-if="css_max_count[i] == true` works fine, but if I add a `return`, then this code does not work. Any reasons?

short code:

```
<div class="ui form" v-for="(im, i) in sorted_listim"> 
    <div  class="ui left pointing red basic label" v-if="css_max_count[i] == true">
        {{im.count_buy}}
    </div>

    <div @click="add_dar(i)" class="ui right small basic green button" ><h3>+</h3>
    </div>

</div>


add_dar(i) {
    if (im.count_buy < count) {
        this.css_max_count[i] = true
        // return - ??????
    } else this.css_max_count[i] = false
}
```

Comment: your `v-for` is incorrect syntax, should be: `v-for="(im, i) in sorted_listim"`

Comment: This is a valid syntax and does not affect this problem. Such a moment that in the presence of 'return', it works, the second time, and without warfare normally. I'm confused.

Comment: Check out the docs here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html.  Does not seem to be a valid syntax, it is possible it works but when you use syntax that is not prescribed by the docs you run the risk of all sorts of side effects

Comment: I already wrote that it does not affect this problem. This syntax works. This problem how to solve, why does it arise, besides the syntax, is there an idea?

Comment: Another issue with the code is that if your function is referencing `im` it should receive it as a parameter, while it is implicit inline it is not in the `methods` section which where I presume your function is.
Try:
```add_dar(im, i) {....}```

Comment: I’ve been working with vue.js for a long time, I don’t need basic advice on where things are. This is not a complete code, so it is easier to understand. The code works, it stops working when the "return" appears. It works with the 2nd attempt in the browser. Try to model it yourself, while the code is completely correct and in the console the value changes to "true". But the browser does not react, as if reactivity disappears in the presence of "return", but this should not be.

Comment: I cannot really comment much more on your code since you are not providing the full code. In general the first step to solving any problem is to make sure your code is written correctly however experienced you are.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a return to the expression, an error occurs because it generates invalid javascript.
The way vue's v-if works is it accepts an expression, which wrapped up in a new `Function` object, which contains its own return.

```
function checkExpression (exp: string, text: string, warn: Function, range?: Range) {
  try {
    new Function(`return ${exp}`)
  }
  ...
  ...
```

The difference between the two is `return css_max_count[i] == true` vs `return return css_max_count[i] == true`.

Adding `return` makes an invalid function and an error is thrown.     You should have seen an error in your console when this happened because it gets warned out, regardless of environment.

See [checkExpression](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ab50e8e1da2f4f944af683252481728485fedf16/src/compiler/error-detector.js) in the vue error-detector for the source.

Comment: There are no errors in my console. Moreover, the console shows in both cases console.log (this.css_max_count [i]) True. But visually displayed in the browser, only if there is no 'return'. It is very strange!